# Drawing a shape using delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

My task - create own delegate & event. Count counts the number, when an event occurs, a rectangle is drawn on Form1. No errors occur, but drawing a rectangle does not occur. A method of drawing a rectangle in the Rect class. I can't figure out why?
Count.cs

```
public delegate void MyDel(object sender, MyEventArgs e);    
public class MyEventArgs
{
    public Graphics G { get; set; }
    public MyEventArgs(Graphics g) { G = g; }
}
class Count
{
    Graphics g;        
    public event MyDel DrawIt;
    public int N { get; set; }
    public Count(int n) { N = n; }
    public void CountIt(int N)
    {
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            a += i;
            if (a > 10)
               OnCount();
        }
    }
    public void OnCount()
    {
        MyDel handler = DrawIt;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new MyEventArgs(g));
    }
}
```

Rect.cs

```
class Rect
{...        
    public void DrawRect(Graphics g){g.DrawRectangle(P, X, Y, Width, Height);}
}
```

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Count c = new Count(10);
        Rect r = new Rect(new Pen(Color.Red, 5), 50, 50, 100, 100);
        c.DrawIt += (s, e) => { r.DrawRect(g); };            
    }        
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to call `Count.CountIt(int)` for the event to fire and I don't see that.  Unrelated, `Count.OnCount` should be `protected` or `private`.

Comment: @lupanton and to add to Zer0 comment as soon as you resize or cause a redraw of the screen it will disappear as it currently only happen when the form load the first time. You need to do that on the `OnDraw` of the form if you want it refreshed

Comment: Essentially, never use CreateGraphics.

Comment: You cannot store the Graphics object. It will be invalid as soon as the Control is repainted. You could have `c.DrawIt += (s, e) => { this.Invalidate(); };`. In the **Paint()** event of the Control (here, a Form), you then draw a new Rectangle. With the current setup, the Rectangle could be a Field, but, apparently, you're assigning to this Rectangle fixed dimensions. So, you should re-design that, too.